# How to use Memory Cache in AuthorizeFilter like Controller?

Tags: asp.net-core, action-filter

I have a global AuthorizeFilter as the following:

```
public class MyAuthorizationFilter : AuthorizeFilter { 

     public MyAuthorizationFilter(Authorization policy) : base(policy) { }

     public override Task OnAuthorizationAsync(AuthorizationFilterContext context) { ... }

}
```

And what I have done in Startup.cs:

```
services.AddMvc(x => {
     x.Filters.Add(new MyAuthorizationFilter(new AuthorizationPolicyBuilder().RequireAuthenticateUser().Build())); 
});
```

And I have added the service too

```
services.AddMemoryCache();
```

It seems the filter doesn't support DI that the way controller does.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

In asp.net core, dependency injection into the filters is supported. Read the section "Dependency Injection" in the official documentation.
[Filters in ASP.Net Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters)

You need to implement the Service Filter or Type Filter.

Another way to resolve the service would be like

```
var service = filterContext.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService<IMemoryCache>();
```

Comment: using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;

Answer (score 2):

use this in `ActionFilterAttribute`

```
IMemoryCache _cache = context.HttpContext.RequestServices.GetService(typeof(IMemoryCache)) as IMemoryCache;
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).